# Appending matching strings to specific lines (sed/bash)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

Using bash/sed, I am trying to search for matching string and when a match is found it appends that variable to the end of the applicable line.

Two lists:

```
[linuxbox tmp]$ cat lista
a 23
c 4
e 55
b 2
f 44
d 74
[linuxbox tmp]$ cat listb
a 3
e 34
c 84
b 1
f 500
d 666666

#!/bin/bash
rm -rf listc

cat listb |while read rec
do
    var1="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $1 }')"
    var2="$(echo $rec | awk '{ print $2 }')"
    if egrep "^$var1" lista; then
            sed "/^$var1/ s/$/ $var2/1" lista >> listc
    fi
done
```

when I run it I get:

```
[linuxbox tmp]$ ./blah.sh
a 23
e 55
c 4
b 2
f 44
d 74

[linuxbox tmp]$ cat listc
a 23 3
c 4
e 55
b 2
f 44
d 74
a 23
c 4
e 55 34
b 2
f 44
d 74
a 23
c 4 84
e 55
b 2
f 44
d 74
a 23
c 4
e 55
b 2  1
f 44
d 74
a 23
c 4
e 55
b 2
f 44 500
d 74
a 23
c 4
e 55
b 2
f 44
d 74 666666
```

The output i'm trying to get to is:

```
a 23 3
e 55 34
c 4 84
b 2  1
f 44 500
d 74 666666
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `sed` with `-n` and append a `p` to the substitute command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind getting a sorted output:

```
join <(sort lista) <(sort listb)
```

Comment: All work no problem; however, this is the most concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { if ($1 in array) print $1, array[$1], $2 }' lista listb
```

Results:

```
a 23 3
e 55 34
c 4 84
b 2 1
f 44 500
d 74 666666
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input files (no duplicate keys in a single file), the following will do the trick:

```
>> for key in $(awk '{print $1}' lista) ; do
+>    echo $key $(awk -vK=$key '$1==K{$1="";print}' lista listb)
+> done

a 23 3
c 4 84
e 55 34
b 2 1
f 44 500
d 74 666666
```